# Passport.js logout session destroy works with POSTMAN but not with the React app. How to fix this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, passport.js, logout

I have an Express backend and trying to set up Passport authentication. Login process works fine and the session token is stored as a cookie. When logging out, clearCookies don't destroy the cookies in the browser. However the process works just fine when I make the calls via Postman.

I've set `{ withCredentials: true }`in the axios config and `{ credentials: true }` in the CORS settings in the backend. I've also set the path in the clearCookies options.

```
// BACKEND LOGOUT
exports._logout = (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy(err => {
    if (err) res.status(422).send(err);
    req.logout();
    res.clearCookie("connect.sid", {domain: 'localhost', path: 
'/'}).status(200).send('Logged out!.')
  });
};

// FRONTEND LOGOUT (REACT/REDUX)
export function logOut() {
return {
    type: 'LOG_OUT',
    payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
            .post(process.env.ACCOUNT_HOST + `/logout`, {withCredentials: true})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                notification.error({
                    message: 'Log In Error',
                    description: error.message,
                    duration: null
                });
                reject(error);
            });
    })
};
}
```

When I call the endpoint with Postman it clears the cookies and isAuth function returns the expected. Any ideas why it's not clearing the cookies in the browser? Thank you.

Comment: Are the cookie settings for logging in *identical* what you are passing to `clearCookie`?

Comment: Yes, they are the same name, path and domain.

Comment: could you show that code? Just for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I am not completely sure where the settings for login are as I'm not writing the backend code. However, the cookie has the same name, path and domain when I check through devtools. I just realized that it's not even about clearing the cookies as I deleted `clearCookie` and tried on postman, and it still worked even though the cookie with a session id was there. So when I make the calls on postman, the express session gets destroyed and doesn't comeback on an isAuth call. When I do the same thing on the browser, the session still gets destroyed, but comes back when I refresh the page.

Comment: So I am guessing the session corresponding to that session id does not get completely destroyed when I make the call from my react app.

Comment: IIRC `logout` only clears the `user` object from the request? Can you try using `req.session.destroy` instead? Given you don't control the session creation it should give you more consistency as the session store will be responsible for removing the cookie.

Comment: Do you mean getting rid of `req.logout()` ? Because I am already using req.session.destroy. I tried getting rid of req.logout. I even set sessionStore and sessionID keys to null too. when the logout endpoint is called, there is literally nothing in `req` about the user. But when isAuth is called, `req.user` has the user. I don't understand how.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter axios takes on a post request is the body of the request and not the options, so currently you send { withCredentials: true } as body, and not the cookies. So passport doesn't have the cookie and can't destroy the session. This should work:

```js
axios.post(process.env.ACCOUNT_HOST + `/logout`, {}, {withCredentials: true})
```